# How to load an aspx file into .Net class object?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to modify existing `aspx` file using a desktop application. Now, I want to load an `aspx` file into a .net class object just like a `XmlDocument`. But, I cannot use `XmlDocument` to load the `.aspx` file it throws error if the file is containing some kind of code which is invalid for `XmlDocument` `Attributes`.

So, I need to know that is it possible to get each and every element from the `.aspx` file with its `attributes` and its `value`.

I know its kind of difficult to determine whether value written in a table cell (i.e. `<td>`) is a simple text or a html or `aspx` element. But, I think its possible to understand because every element starts with `<` and close with `>`.

Your minor input may help me a lot.

Comment: Why you want to do this? May be you have better solution if you explain why you want to do so?

Comment: @Adil , I want to display all the elements in Tree control. User can select element or explore it by expanding tree nodes. user can also copy definition of element from the tree node. When user selects any element then the aspx  code definition should be displayed in textbox including its child element.

Comment: What is user start playing with html and breaks it? These kind of feature are avaible in Code editors and might be used. Did you try HTML document class instead of XmlDocument?

Comment: @Shell Take a look at this article: [ASP Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6888/ASP-Parser). It seems it's exactly what you are looking for. Also you can try [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Valid HTML is not by default valid XML: XML needs to close all elements: every `<p>` needs a `</p>`, `<br>` needs to be `<br/>` and so on. Better use something that understands HTML (see comment by Reza).

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei [ASP Parser] (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6888/ASP-Parser) works great. This is what I exactly wants.